# How do i make Recyclerview appear on top of mapview

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-mapview

I have a recycler view which appears when users enter something on a textbox in my Android app. I also have a mapview just below the textbox but when the recycler view appears it goes behind the mapview. I want the recycler view to appear on top of the mapview.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
   >


    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp">
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <Chronometer
        android:layout_marginTop = "450dp"
        android:id="@+id/chronometer"
        android:format="%s"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:includeFontPadding="false"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_id"
        android:layout_marginTop= "450dp"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft ="20dp"
        android:layout_marginStart ="20dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Trip Distance"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
        android:textColorHighlight="@android:color/primary_text_dark"
        android:textSize="25dp"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_marginTop = "380dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft ="20dp"
        android:layout_marginStart ="20dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:text="@string/self_destruct"
        android:id="@+id/self_destruct"
        android:onClick="selfDestruct"
        android:layout_marginBottom = "10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_button"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"   />

    <Button
        android:layout_marginTop = "380dp"
        android:layout_marginRight ="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd ="20dp"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:text="@string/trip_details"
        android:id="@+id/trip_details"
        android:onClick="sendTripdetails"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_button"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

    <Button
        android:layout_marginTop = "60dp"
        android:layout_marginRight ="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd ="20dp"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"

        android:text="@string/share_trip"
        android:id="@+id/share_trip"
        android:onClick="ShareTrip"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_button"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

    <Button
        android:layout_marginTop = "60dp"
        android:layout_marginRight ="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd ="20dp"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="@string/pick_contact"
        android:id="@+id/pickcontact"
        android:onClick="ShareTrip"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_button"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

    <Button
        android:layout_marginTop = "60dp"
        android:layout_marginRight ="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd ="20dp"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="@string/send_sms"
        android:id="@+id/sendsms"
        android:onClick="ShareTrip"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_button"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_height="0px"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/search_box"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:paddingBottom="12dp"
        android:paddingTop="12dp"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:hint="@string/search_hint"
        android:background="@drawable/bottom_border"
        />



    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/myrecyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:layout_marginTop="90dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
         android:scrollbars="vertical" />

    <com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView

        android:id="@+id/mapview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
        android:layout_height="240dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/clear_txt"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="120dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:background="@android:drawable/ic_menu_close_clear_cancel" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_1"
        android:layout_marginLeft= "25dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textColorHighlight="@android:color/primary_text_dark"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textSize="18dp"/>

    <com.example.docuwind.maplive.RoundedImageView

        android:id="@+id/imageView_round"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: post your complete xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Views which placed first in **RelativeLayout** *ViewGroup* will draw first on UI, so interchange the order of your views can solve your problem.

```
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView
    android:id="@+id/mapview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
    android:layout_height="240dp" />

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/myrecyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:layout_marginTop="90dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" />
</RelativeLayout>
```